# Export Python dict of nested lists of varying lengths to csv. If nested list has > 1 entry, expand to column before moving to next key

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary, nested-lists

I have the following dictionary of lists

```
d = {1: ['1','B1',['C1','C2','C3']], 2: ['2','B2','C15','D12'], 3: ['3','B3'], 4: ['4', 'B4', 'C4', ['D1', 'D2']]}
```

writing that to a csv using

```
with open('test.csv', "w", newline = '') as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(headers)
writer.writerows(d.values())
```

gives me a csv that looks like

```
A     B            C                D
1    B1     ['C1','C2',C3']
2    B2           C15             D12
3    B3
4    B4            C4          ['D1','D2']
```

If there is a multiple item list in the value (nested list?), I would like that list to be expanded down the column like this

```
A     B     C      D
1    B1    C1
1          C2 
1          C3
2    B2    C15    D12
3    B3
4    B4    C4      D1
4                  D2
```

I'm fairly new to python and can't seem to figure out a way to do what I need after a few days sifting through forums and banging my head on the wall.  I think I may need to break apart the nested lists, but I need to keep them tied to their respective "A" value.  Columns A and B will always have 1 entry, columns C and D can have 1 to X number of entries.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it might be easier to make a list of lists, with appropriately-located empty spaces, than what you're doing. Here's something that might do:

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

def condense(dct):
    # get the maximum number of columns of any list
    num_cols = len(max(dct.values(), key=len)) - 1
    # Ignore the key, it's not really relevant.
    for _, v in dct.items():
        # first, memorize the index of this list, 
        # since we need to repeat it no matter what
        idx = v[0]
        # next, use zip_longest to make a correspondence.
        # We will deliberately make a 2d list, 
        # and we will later withdraw elements from it one by one.
        matrix = [([]     if elem is None else
                   [elem] if not isinstance(elem, list) else 
                   elem[:]  # soft copy to avoid altering original dict
                  ) for elem, _ in zip_longest(v[1:], range(num_cols), fillvalue=None)
                 ]
        # Now, we output the top row of the matrix as long as it has contents
        while any(matrix):
            # If a column in the matrix is empty, we put an empty string.
            # Otherwise, we remove the row as we pass through it,
            # progressively emptying the matrix top-to-bottom
            # as we output a row, we also remove that row from the matrix.
            # *-notation is more convenient than concatenating these two lists.
            yield [idx, *((col.pop(0) if col else '') for col in matrix)] 
            # e.g. for key 0 and a matrix that looks like this:
            #    [['a1', 'a2'],
            #     ['b1'],
            #     ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']]
            # this would yield the following three lists before moving on:
            #    ['0', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1']
            #    ['0', 'a2', '',   'c2']
            #    ['0', '',   '',   'c3']
            # where '' should parse into an empty column in the resulting CSV.
```

The biggest thing to note here is that I use `isinstance(elem, list)` as a shorthand to check whether the thing is a list (which you need to be able to do, one way or another, to flatten or rounden lists as we do here). If you have more complicated or more varied data structures, you'll need to improvise with this check - maybe write a helper function `isiterable()` that tries to iterate through and returns a boolean based on whether doing so produced an error.

That done, we can call `condense()` on `d` and have the `csv` module deal with the output.

```
headers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
d = {1: ['1','B1',['C1','C2','C3']], 2: ['2','B2','C15','D12'], 3: ['3','B3'], 4: ['4', 'B4', 'C4', ['D1', 'D2']]}

# condense(d) produces
#   [['1', 'B1', 'C1',  ''   ], 
#    ['1', '',   'C2',  ''   ], 
#    ['1', '',   'C3',  ''   ], 
#    ['2', 'B2', 'C15', 'D12'], 
#    ['3', 'B3', '',     ''  ], 
#    ['4', 'B4', 'C4',  'D1' ], 
#    ['4', '',   '',    'D2' ]]

with open('test.csv', "w", newline = '') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(condense(d))
```

Which produces the following file:

```
A,B,C,D
1,B1,C1,
1,,C2,
1,,C3,
2,B2,C15,D12
3,B3,,
4,B4,C4,D1
4,,,D2
```

This is equivalent to your expected output. Hopefully the solution is sufficiently extensible for you to apply it to your non-MVCE problem.

Comment: GCG - This is EXACTLY what I needed!  Thank you so much for taking the time to provide a complete answer with an explanation.  I'll spend some analyzing what you sent, but you got me "un-stuck". I tried to mark as useful, but below I'm 15 rep...